# linq toList gives timeout on wcf client

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

The WCF client timesout after the return. I have tried increasing the timeout time but that didn't work. When i debug the method there is no problem.

Anyone got a suggestion?

```
public List<Order> ProductsOfUser(string username, string password)
{
    var user = container.UserSet.FirstOrDefault(u => (u.Username == username && u.Password == password));
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    var resultuserId = user.Id;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(resultuserId);

    var orders3 = container.OrderSet.Where(o => o.UserId == user.Id).ToList();

    return orders3;
}
```

This is the query that linq creates :

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],

[Extent1].[CustName] AS [CustName], 

[Extent1].[OrderDate] AS [OrderDate]
,
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]

FROM [dbo].[OrderSet] AS [Extent1]}
```

Logfile : http://pastebin.com/Q6VpmhmW

Comment: How large is the list that's being created?

Comment: Complete shot in the dark, but make sure the service reference is up-to-date.

Comment: Another thought: Maybe try removing the ToList and just return a very simple list with 1 or 2 elements just to see if the issue goes away.

Comment: there is only one element in the list. Service reference is also updated :)

Comment: Realize that the underlying query is not executed until `ToList` is called, so the problem is likely you have a poorly-performing query.  Use a tracing tool to determine what the query is and see if it can be optimized by adding an index or two.

Comment: Also, authenticating a user in the same method that you return related data seems like a bad design.  You should probably factor that out into a separate method for reuse.

Comment: You could also try to change your query to `container.OrderSet.Where(o => o.UserId == resultuserId).ToList();` since you already capture the ID into a variable.

Comment: for the authentication i'm going to use a separate method, and i already tried to use the ID from the variable. But i always get the same timeout. i'm going to try optimizing the query

Comment: added the query that linq creates in the topic, for me it looks ok.

Comment: What is consuming this WCF service?

Comment: i'm testing it with the WCF Test client. added logfile to the post see pastebin log

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it

added [DataContract(IsReference = true)] to the User class and everything works smoothly now.